# Django POST returns empty - DRF + recaptcha

Tags: python, django, post, django-rest-framework, recaptcha

I'm trying to make a POST request to Django and it arrives empty to the view.

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework import generics, views

class TESTViewSet(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        st = f'test: {request.POST} - {request.data} '
        s_obj = serializers.RecaptchaSerializer(
            data=request.data, context={"request": request}
        )
        return HttpResponse(st)
```

The purpose is to test recaptcha with django rest framework, but I haven't even got there yet. The issue is the request always arriving at the view empty of any info. The page renders renders "`test: -` "

The template rendered in the page:

```
<div class="">
    test
    <form method="post" action="/api/test_recaptcha/">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <label for="ntest">Select:</label>
        <select name="ntest" id="ntest">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      <label for="stest">Text:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="stest" name="stest" value=""><br>
      <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="{MY CAPTCHA PUBLIC KEY}"></div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

It renders what is in the view, so the route is ok. I inspected the browser request, and all the fields of the post request are filled, including the g-captcha. However when it arrives at the view it's empty.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try to print and debug

Comment: This is running in a AWS Lightsail instance, using Apache as WSGI. I've tried to log and print, but it doesn't get logged into apache logs. That's why I'm trying to return the values as a HTTP response. In anycase, if there was anything there it would be in the string.

Comment: Don't you have a development environment for this? Maybe use pdb to debug